# Slack API: how to get state of all input/action elements at once upon submit

Tags: api, block, slack, interactive

I'm trying to build rich, interactive Slack messages. Example: message with date picker, set of checkboxes and a long text. Upon submit (if modal) or push of an action button, I'd like to receive the current state of all interactive components.
I have tried regular messages with both input and action blocks...also tried modals. I get a message from Slack for every individual change to an interactive object, but not the state of all objects at once. Since the receiver of the interaction payload is stateless, this makes it impossible for me to properly react to the message.

Am I missing something? Appreciate every bit of advice.

Answer (score 1):

OK, error seems to be on my side. I was just looking at the action payload preview in the Slack Block Kit Builder. When actually posting a message I see the state of all elements in the response.